# Spring + Hibernate + Tomcat Dependency problems

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, tomcat6, noclassdeffounderror

when I run tomcat and the war is deployed I get :
**NoClassDefFoundError : org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap**

```
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
 ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
```

What is strange is that I got the `commons-collections-2.1.jar` (I even tried 3.1) in my WEB-INF lib folder.

Edit :
I did copy the `commons-collections` from `WEB-INF/lib` to `Tomcat lib` and it seems to work. However I won't be able to do that on the production server, why isn't it taking my `WEB-INF/lib` version ?

Comment: Could be a classloader problem. (Yuck!) Good luck!

Comment: if the jar works in tomcat/lib but not in WEB-INF/lib you may need to do a proper restart. The error is NoClassDefFound which is not the same as ClassNotFound. As mentioned above the classloader may got confused by something else (another version of the jar or the class). Maybe the LRUMap is also part of a tomcat-jar?

Comment: Looks like a class that uses org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap is loaded by a classloader that is higher in the hierarchy than your Webapp Class Loader. See 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html.

Comment: Isn't there a way to detect more precisely where the problem might be ?

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue What mean of  `Tomcat lib`?

Comment: @aircraft the lib folder directly in tomcat server tree (ex: /srv/tomcat-xxx/lib)

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I did put version 3.2.1 of commons-collections and the error disappeared. I unfortunately still don't know which library is depending on this version. Even `mvn dependency:tree` didn't help ...

Comment: can you post your `pom.xml` and spring bean definitions (relevant portions of that)

Answer (score 1):

I had this exception when I was with `xdoclet` on dependencies.

If you are with this dependency, just exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same probleme, maybe it's too late to approve the answer but it's still benefitial for people who will have this problem in the futur.
So I exclude commons-collections from net.sf.jasperreports, after that the tomcat runs perfectly whithout any problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```