# Cannot start Tomcat application

Tags: java, maven, gwt, tomcat7

Hello I've deployed a little web application thats using GWT with Tomcat Web Application Manager.
When I'm trying to start is I get the following error:

```
    Okt 01, 2014 2:47:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error listenerStart
   Okt 01, 2014 2:47:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SCHWERWIEGEND: Context [/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] startup failed du
    e to previous errors
```

Is there anything i have to notice by building or deploying the war? Thanks for your help!

*edit*

I think all dependencies are not in path of applications runtime:

because this exception happens:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap

the jars are copied to WEB-INF/lib and I've also tried to unzip all jars to WEB-INF/classes. Nothing of this helps.

How can I fix the maven build?

Comment: Look at server logfile. There must be more exceptions.

Comment: "startup failed due to previous errors" - the software is trying to tell you something - that you need to look higher up in the log output for the actual error.

Comment: look up in the logs for errors (startup failed due to previous errors)

Comment: It's related to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045262/spring-hibernate-tomcat-dependency-problems.