# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap

Tags: java, hibernate

Before asking this question, I've searched stackoverflow, but I did not get a good answer.

[Spring + Hibernate + Tomcat Dependency problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045262/spring-hibernate-tomcat-dependency-problems)

When I debug the method:

[image]

My issue log is below:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap

   at org.hibernate.util.SimpleMRUCache.init(SimpleMRUCache.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.util.SimpleMRUCache.<init>(SimpleMRUCache.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.<init>(QueryPlanCache.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1842)
    at com.ypd.a.entity.App.testHello(App.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:289)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(MethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(MethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:155)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:87)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:87)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:59)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.LRUMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 34 more
```

The cause by is :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.collections.map.LRUMap

Comment: I've just found something similar: `org.apache.commons.collections.LRUMap` has become `org.apache.commons.collections4.map.LRUMap` Maybe the developer thought the users would be sad without incompatible changes.

Answer (score 2):

There is the obvious explain in your log:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

If you see this type error, you should consider if there is no plug-in library.

What you should do is go to http://mvnrepository.com to search `commons-collections`, and copy the version you want, to add to your pom.xml, and instal it.

Comment: I unchecked lib commons-collections and forgot this, thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been dealing with this issue myself for the past couple days.  I'm still having trouble with Tomcat 9 but on tomcat 8 I was able to get around the error by adding deps to both commons-collections and commons-collections4 like this:

```html
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.0'
compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.2'
```

Then I just replaced all uses of the package org.apache.commons.collections
with org.apache.commons.collections4 in the code base.